# Can not unset rows of a view programmatically

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I created a view of terms using views_tree module. I need to remove some of the terms under some conditions. This is my code

```
function THEME_views_pre_render(&$views) {
    for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($views->result) ; $i++)
       unset($views->result[$i]);
}
```

But it still prints all of the terms and doesn't delete any of them. I tried this code

```
function THEME_views_pre_render(&$views) {
    for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($views->result) ; $i++){
        $views->result[$i]->taxonomy_term_data_name ="Hello";
    }
}
```

It successfully renamed every term, But when I tried the following code, every name turned back to what it was from the beginning and nothing removed.

```
function THEME_views_pre_render(&$views) {
    for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($views->result) ; $i++){
        $views->result[$i]->taxonomy_term_data_name ="Hello";
        unset($views->result[$i]);
    }
}
```

How can I remove some terms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work on `template.php` too. Module implementation does not look mandatory here.
I have noticed a few issues in the code sample that you have pasted.

1. There is a typo. It should be **$view** not **$views**.
2. Instead of

   ```
   for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($view->result) ; $i++){
   }
   ```

   Do

   ```
   $sizeof_result = sizeof($view->result);
   for($i = 0 ; $i < $sizeof_result ; $i++)
   ```

The following code works for me:

```
function MYTHEME_views_pre_render(&$view){
  if($view->name == 'MY_VIEW'){
    $sizeof_result = sizeof($view->result);
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $sizeof_result ; $i++){
      //IF Condition
        unset($view->result[$i]);
    } 
  }
}
```

The reason for using variable `$sizeof_result` instead of `sizeof($view->result)` in `for loop` is:

For each execution of the loop, the value of sizeof($view->result) changes(decreases by 1). Due to this, the for loops does not work as expected.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. It is very surprising that the name `view` is important

Answer (score 0):

Use basically the same code in THEME_views_post_execute(&$view)
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7.x-3.x

Comment: I tried it, drupal doesn't run that function at all. I cleared the caches too

Comment: I'd recommend putting it in a custom module and not the theme.

Comment: I swear I've unset rows before in the hook_view_pre_render() before though too..But I always use custom modules. Maybe somebody will come along with a theme based answer, if it has to be there.

Comment: Ok, I will try it in module level implementation

Answer (score 0):

As jackrabbithanna said, maybe implementation of the code in a module may resolve your problem, I also had excluded some view results in a project using an auxiliary result set as code below , hope that helps:

```
/**
  * Implementation of hook_views_pre_render().
  */
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $new_result = [];
  foreach ($view->result as $key => $value) {
   if(SHOULD NOT EXCLUDED)
    $new_result[] = $value;
  }
  $view->result = $new_result;
}
```